# draw9patch image not looking good when I downloaded from my SVN

Tags: android, image, png

I created draw9patch image and its working fine in my machine.
I uploaded to accurev(like SVN) my colleague downloaded the workspace and he installed in 10' inch device and we noticed that the image is not showing fine. 
It looks like normal image with stretched.

what happened to my draw9patch image? the file name is showing as xxx.9.png.

when we download from server will draw9patch image will get change?

//this is my 9 patch image
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not likely that your image changed when you pulled it from your repository. It is more likely that the image you've created simply does not stretch very well on a 10" device.

Did you include one image for each screen density?

Related:
[How to use 9 patch images in android for different-2  densities(like mdpi,ldpi,hdpi).?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583359/how-to-use-9-patch-images-in-android-for-different-2-densitieslike-mdpi-ldpi-h)

Comment: if its an draw9 means only 1 image is enough it will fit for all.

Comment: It does mean that the image will scale according to predefined specifications, but it does not mean that an image created for a low density will necessarily look good when displayed on a high density screen.

Comment: actually its looking good in all densities I already checked in 7' 10' with mdpi and ldpi but the think is when It is downloaded from server its not showing the behavior of 9 patch.